# Python File Server Only Works with One Thread Running

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-multithreading

I have made a file server on python using sockets and threads. The program is supposed to allow the client to upload and download files from the server.

The program works perfectly when only one thread is running, but when both threads are running the server gives an error when trying to upload a file, and when trying to download the program just stops doing anything after the client enters 'Y' to initiate the download.

Here is the code for the client:

```
import socket
import os

def DownloadFile(s, host, port):
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send(str.encode('DNLD'))
    filename = input('Filename? ->')
    if filename != 'q':
        s.send(str.encode(filename))
        data = s.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filesize = data[6:]
            message = input('File Exists, ' + str(filesize) + ' Bytes. Download? (Y/N) ->')
            if message == 'Y' or message == 'y':
                s.send(str.encode('OK'))
                f = open('copy of '+filename, 'wb')
                data = s.recv(2048)
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while totalRecv < int(filesize):
                    data = s.recv(2048)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    print('{}'.format(round((totalRecv/float(filesize))*100),2)+'% Complete')
                print('Download Complete!')
                s.close()

        else:
            print('File does not exist')
            s.close()
    Main()

def UploadFile(s, host, port):
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send(str.encode('UPLD'))
    filename = input('Filename? ->')
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        filesize = str(filesize)
        s.send(str.encode('EXISTS ' + filename))
        s.send(str.encode(filesize))
        ready = input('Ready to upload. Proceed? (Y/N) ->')
        if ready == 'Y' or ready == 'y':
            s.send(str.encode('OK'))
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(2048)
                s.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != '':
                    bytesToSend = f.read(2048)
                    s.send(bytesToSend)
                s.close()
    else:
        print('File does not exist.')
        s.close()
    Main()

def Main(): 
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 10000
    s = socket.socket()
    while True:
        choice = int(input('Please enter your choice:\n\n1. Upload a file to the server.\n2. Download a file from the server\n3. Quit.\n\n->'))
        if choice == 1:
            UploadFile(s, host, port)
            break
        elif choice == 2:
            DownloadFile(s, host, port)
            break
        elif choice == 3:
            s.close()
            break
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid choice.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

And here is the code for the server:

```
import socket
import threading
import os

def SendFile(name, s):
    check = s.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')
    if check == 'DNLD':
        filename = s.recv(2048)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            send = os.path.getsize(filename)
            send = str(send)
            s.send(str.encode('EXISTS ' + send))
            userResponse = s.recv(2048)
            userResponse = userResponse.decode('UTF-8')
            if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
                with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                    bytesToSend = f.read(2048)
                    s.send(bytesToSend)
                    while bytesToSend != '':
                        bytesToSend = f.read(2048)
                        s.send(bytesToSend)
            else:
                s.send(str.encode('ERR'))

    s.close()

def ReceiveFile(name, s):
    check = s.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')
    if check == 'UPLD':
        data = s.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filename = data[6:]
            data = s.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')
            filesize = data
            userResponse = s.recv(2048)
            userResponse = userResponse.decode('UTF-8')
            if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
                f = open('copy of '+filename, 'wb')
                data = s.recv(2048)
                totalRecv = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while totalRecv < int(filesize):
                    data = s.recv(2048)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                print('Download Complete!')

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 10000
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print('Server Started')

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print('Client Connected: ' + str(addr))
        Send = threading.Thread(target=SendFile, args=('sendThread', c))
        Send.start()
        Receive = threading.Thread(target=ReceiveFile, args=('retrThread', c))
        Receive.start()

    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

If I were to comment out Send.start() or Receive.start() then whatever thread isn't commented out would work perfectly.

Here is the error given in the server when trying to upload a file with both threads running:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "(file location)", line 28, in ReceiveFile
    check = s.recv(2048).decode('UTF-8')
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

And here is the output in the client when trying to download a file when both threads are running:

```
Please enter your choice:

1. Upload a file to the server.
2. Download a file from the server
3. Quit.

->2
Filename? ->cat.jpg
File Exists,  10634 Bytes. Download? (Y/N) ->Y
```

Nothing else happens after entering Y.

If anyone knows what is going wrong I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way io and threads work. You have here 2 threads competing from the same input data. One will get first packet be it for it or not, and it is likely that one of the following packet will be eaten by the other thread => the first one will never see it!

You can delegate the processing of a *conversation* to a thread but to a single one that will call a send or receive function once it will have identified the request.

That is not all. TCP is a *stream* protocol. Packets can be splitted or re-assembled by any piece along the connection (sender, receiver and any gateway). So you should use *delimiters* to tell the peer that a name or a command if complete. And good practices recommend to pass the size when sending binary data, here again for the peer to know when the data is complete.

Good luck in your journey is the socket world ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand what you mean about the threads competing for the same data, but I put something in to try to stop that. The client sends a string to the server, and if it matches the expected string in the server code, then the upload/download code starts. Is this not enough to prevent them from stealing each others data?  Also thanks for the tips on using delimiters and passing file sizes.